# get_edit_post_link() not working as expected when passed id in plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

So inside my plugin I have the following code.  It gets a question from a custom_post. I'm processing it here so that further updates can be done by AJAX/JSON and the page only has to be configured for one type of data source.

```
$observations = new WP_Query($args);  
if ( $observations-> have_posts() ) :
    $questionpost = $observations->posts[0];
    $question = array (
        'id' => $questionpost->ID,
        'title' => $questionpost->post_title,
        'name' =>  $questionpost->post_name,
        'excerpt' => $questionpost->post_excerpt,
        'content' => $questionpost->post_content,
        'code' => get_post_meta( $questionpost->ID, 'code', true ),
        'edit_link' => get_edit_post_link($questionpost->ID),
    );
    if ( has_post_thumbnail($questionpost->ID) ) {
        $question['thumbnail'] = get_the_post_thumbnail( $questionpost->ID, 'full', array('class' => 'card-img-top')); 
    } else {
        $question['thumbnail'] = get_template_directory_uri()."/img/no-image.png";
    }
    print_r($question);
}
```

It all works fine except for the get_edit_post_link - here is print_r dump:

```
Array ( [id] => 208 [title] => Main ... pipework. [name] => nr-60 [excerpt] => [content] => The ... external. [code] => NR [edit_link] => [thumbnail] => http://.../img/no-image.png )
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post_link suggests we can pass an ID so I don't see why this is blank.

Comment: Do you have enough permissions to edit that post?

Comment: You beauty.  Spent so long tweaking with the front end and not visiting admin I had been logged out.    Thanks

Comment: I've created the answer for generations to come.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the `get_edit_post_link()` function [source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_edit_post_link/) this can happen in following conditions:

- there is no such post;
- there is no such post type;
- you don't have enough permissions to edit the post;
- `_edit_link` was changed during post type registration.

The first two are not the case since the ID is available. The fourth is a bad practice: *not for general use — core developers [recommend](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Parameters) you don't use this when registering your own post type*.

In this case, the user doesn't have enough permissions. According to the OP's comment under the question, he had been logged out, which is the same sort of thing.

Comment: I need post link inside ajax automatization process without any permission, the edit link will be sent via email. There should be an option to get it without checking for permissions?! if the user doesnt have permission, he's not gonna be able to see the link anyway. For my case I had to use admin_url( 'post.php?post='. $id .'&action=edit', 'https' )

Answer (score 1):

This might be one of those times when certain functions work better as part of the loop. Although you're using a loop, you're not actually using the full WP loop functionality.

Try adding `'posts_per_page'=> 1` to your `$args` to get just the one post, and then replacing `$questionpost = $observations->posts[0];` with the missing loop construct, ie: `while($observations->have_posts()) : $observations->the_post();` (not forgetting the closing `endwhile;` of course). This will then allow you to use the normal in-loop functions (eg, `get_the_ID()`, `get_the_title()`, etc) and try using `get_edit_post_link()` without passing the ID to it.

Comment: I moved away from the loop because I only really want a single random post.  Anyway.  I was being sloooow - I'd spent so long focused on the front end I had been logged out of admin and not noticed.   Thanks for the ideas thou.

Comment: I'm dressing down my old posts and I've found some bad non-siimple-english ones. Can I help you again? There could be a better solution. Let us share it.